# React-router-DOM is refreshing my context state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-context, react-state

I've looked up for hours and I just can't find any solution for my problem.

I'm developing an app that uses react context and I'm also using react-router-dom to navigate through my pages.

This context file, has a initial state, for I am using useReducer hook to change it.
But when I navigate along application, like changing or switch pages my state realoads and I can't get data from my state unless I make a new get request.

I've read somewhere that react-router-dom is refreshing my pages so I can't make it.

Is there any tip you guys can give me?

Actually I can't think about a solution since I am confusing about how do I make the state "permanent"

there is my index:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { AppProvider } from "./context";
import "./styles.css";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import FriendshipAccess from "./pages/FriendshipAccess";
import SearchPage from "./pages/SearchPage";
import EditAccount from "./pages/EditAccount";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route path="/account/edit" element={<EditAccount />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/users/:nickname" element={<FriendshipAccess />} />
          <Route path="/users/search" element={<SearchPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Here is my context:

```
import React, { useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import {
  registerNewUser,
  authUser, //MARKDOWN OF THE TASK!!!!!
  getUserPosts,
  accessUserProfile,
  validateUserToken,
  editAccountData,
} from "./operations/operations";

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const initialState = {
  userState: {
    userData: {},
    userPosts: [],
  },
  serverMessages: {},
  accessToken: false,
  accessedUserPage: {
    userData: {},
    userPosts: {},
  },
};

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const registerSubmitHandler = async (userInputs) => {
    const registeredUser = await registerNewUser(userInputs);
    dispatch({ type: "REGISTER_USER", payload: registeredUser.data });
  };

  const authUserCredentials = async (userCredentials) => {
    const userDataFromDb = await authUser(userCredentials);
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", userDataFromDb.token);
    dispatch({
      type: "AUTH_USER",
      payload: userDataFromDb,
    });
  };

  const getUserDataByToken = async (token) => {
    const userDataFromDb = await validateUserToken(token);
    dispatch({ type: "LOGGED_GET_DATA", payload: userDataFromDb });
  };

  const editUserAccount = async (token, accountData) => {
    const editedUserData = await editAccountData(token, accountData);
    dispatch({ type: "EDIT_USER_ACCOUNT", payload: editedUserData });
  };

  const getUserPostsData = async (token) => {
    const postsDataFromDb = await getUserPosts(token);
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_USER_POSTS", payload: postsDataFromDb });
  };

  const getBuddyData = async (nicknameParam) => {
    const userDataFromDb = await accessUserProfile(nicknameParam);
    dispatch({ type: "ACCESS_FRIEND_PAGE", payload: userDataFromDb });
  };

  const userLogout = async () => {
    await localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
    const emptyState = {
      ...state,
      userState: {
        userData: "",
        userPosts: "",
      },
    };
    dispatch({ type: "USER_LOGOUT", payload: emptyState });
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        registerSubmitHandler,
        authUserCredentials,
        getUserPostsData,
        userLogout,
        getBuddyData,
        getUserDataByToken,
        editUserAccount,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppProvider, AppContext };
```

Comment: `AppProvider` is above `BrowserRouter` in the ReactTree, so switching routes should not affect it. Can you clarify in more and better detail what exactly you mean by the state resetting or reloading? How are you navigating around the app?

Comment: So, my initial state, at the top of my context.js file returns me an empty object.
As I log in, follow new users, post content and stuff like this, it returns me the data from my database.
But if I switch pages, it just returns to the initial empty state unless I request data from my database everytime it made necessary

Comment: And how are you switching pages?

Comment: At the page that it made necessary, instead of using "a" element, I'm using "Link" element imported from react router dom

Comment: If you are manually updating the URL in the address bar or using a raw anchor (*`<a>`*) tag this will reload the page and the app will remount with initial state (*unless you are persisting state*). Using the `Link` component should not do this. Can you [edit] to share the links used?

Comment: I've answered this post with a solution, thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything very odd with your code.

Nevertheless, it is a best practise to encapsulate your context value in a memo. If you don't do that, all components which consume this context render more times than they need.

Could you try that please?

```
const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const value = React.useMemo(() => {
    const registerSubmitHandler = async (userInputs) => {
      const registeredUser = await registerNewUser(userInputs);
      dispatch({ type: "REGISTER_USER", payload: registeredUser.data });
    };
  
    const authUserCredentials = async (userCredentials) => {
      const userDataFromDb = await authUser(userCredentials);
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", userDataFromDb.token);
      dispatch({
        type: "AUTH_USER",
        payload: userDataFromDb,
      });
    };
  
    const getUserDataByToken = async (token) => {
      const userDataFromDb = await validateUserToken(token);
      dispatch({ type: "LOGGED_GET_DATA", payload: userDataFromDb });
    };
  
    const editUserAccount = async (token, accountData) => {
      const editedUserData = await editAccountData(token, accountData);
      dispatch({ type: "EDIT_USER_ACCOUNT", payload: editedUserData });
    };
  
    const getUserPostsData = async (token) => {
      const postsDataFromDb = await getUserPosts(token);
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_USER_POSTS", payload: postsDataFromDb });
    };
  
    const getBuddyData = async (nicknameParam) => {
      const userDataFromDb = await accessUserProfile(nicknameParam);
      dispatch({ type: "ACCESS_FRIEND_PAGE", payload: userDataFromDb });
    };
  
    const userLogout = async () => {
      await localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
      const emptyState = {
        ...state,
        userState: {
          userData: "",
          userPosts: "",
        },
      };
      dispatch({ type: "USER_LOGOUT", payload: emptyState });
    };

    return {
      ...state,
      registerSubmitHandler,
      authUserCredentials,
      getUserPostsData,
      userLogout,
      getBuddyData,
      getUserDataByToken,
      editUserAccount,
    };
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
```

Comment: I've edited my question, but I don't put any state change actually, beacause, a lot of stuff on my app changes my state.

Comment: I can't do it right know, but asap I will try it, for now, thank you

Comment: Also, even though I've figured out what was going on, I'll consider your tip!
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

in advance, I would like to thank you for all your help.
I've noticed that in some components that I use material UI, it receives the "href" property, so, this was conflicting with my navigation along the pages, so I've removed the "href" links, and the application works properly, but I figured out things because you guys helped me!
Thank you all, here's a little piece of my code:

```
<Link to="/profile" style={RouterStyledLink}>
  <BottomNavigationAction
    sx={{ color: "#fff", "border-right": "none" }}
    //here was a "href" attribute that refreshed my state!
    label="Home"
    icon={<HomeIcon />}
  />
</Link>
```